# Delete and recreate of NTFS file format in Extended partition will maintain driver letter?

Tags: partition, drivers, ntfs, ext3

One of my computer system is having the disk partition like below

1-Primary (NTFS) (boot)

2-Primary (NTFS) (Windows C: Drive) (windows XP OS) + (software installed)

3-Primary (NTFS) (Windows D: Drive) (software installed)

4-Extended (with 4 logical partitions ext3) linux OS

5-Unallocated

Now i want to create one more extended partition in the unallocated from linux OS. But the KDE partition manager is not allowing as saying that already 4 primary partitions are there.

Now my plan is below (from the Linux OS)

To take a back of the partition "3-Primary (NTFS)".

Drop the partition "3-Primary (NTFS)". So the primary partition count will become 3.

Create one more extended partition in the unallocated.

Add new NTFS file format partition (logical partition) in the newly created extended partition.

Restore the backup to this newly created NTFS file format.

Restart the PC to login windows.

Now the newly created NTFS will be treated as D: drive and all my D: drive installed software work as before? or any other ways there to use the unallocated space without deleting existing drive?

**Moving this question from stackoverflow community to here**

Answer (score 0):

After google, i found the below answer and implemented successfully.

Cant create more than one extended partition. Instead resize the existing extend partition to use the unallocated space. To resize it, use the ubuntu live USB and start the ubuntu os with the option "try with out installing". if the existing partition contain a swap partition then, stop it (using gparted - a partition manager). Then resize the extended partition and create the logical partitions.